# All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `y` is 6, whereas the length of previous arguments ['year'] is 100

Tags: python, arguments, linegraph, plotly-express, graph-data-science

**Library that I used**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Dataset**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4hIL.png

**My Code**

```
sound_features = ['acousticness', 'danceability', 'energy', 'instrumentalness', 'liveness', 'valence']
fig = px.line(year_data, x='year', y=sound_features)
fig.show()
```

**My Output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF529.png

**Ideal Output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwsop.png

Comment: I am not familiar with the library, but what most do is just plotting cartesian coordinates by zipping lists of equal length to get the position of each point. What you need to do is extract the column of values for each sound feature and then pass that as `y`, instead of giving a list of labels as `y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's try this way

```
plot_data = [
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['acousticness'],
        name = 'acousticness'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['danceability'],
        name = 'danceability'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['energy'],
        name = 'energy'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['instrumentalness'],
        name = 'instrumentalness'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['liveness'],
        name = 'liveness'
    ),
    go.Scatter(
        x=year_data['year'],
        y=year_data['valence'],
        name = 'valence'
    )
]

plot_layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis={"type": "category"},
        title='Sound features'
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=plot_data, layout=plot_layout)
pyoff.iplot(fig)
```